# Angular JS - How to assign each item in a json object to a scope variable?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

I have a set json object like

```
var data = {item1: "Hello1",item2:"Hello2",item3:"Hello3",item4:"Hello4",item5:"Hello5"};
```

I want each item to be available in the scope. Like

```
$scope.item1
$scope.item2
...
```

Is it possible in Angular

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
for (var key in data) {
  $scope[key] = p[key]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. get the keys of the object and assign create scope variables like this

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
var data = {item1: "Hello1",item2:"Hello2",item3:"Hello3",item4:"Hello4",item5:"Hello5"};

for(var k in data) {
  $scope[k] = data[k]
}

console.log($scope.item1)
console.log($scope.item2)
console.log($scope.item3)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks sachila.. But you have to make a small correction. $scope[k] = data[k];